# Maximum size of 2D array on Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino, multidimensional-array, arduino-ide, arduino-uno

I tried making an array `double data[640][14]`, but the compiler says that the array size is too big. Can anyone tell me what is the maximum size I can use, and how can I work around this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Arduino Uno has an Atmel 328p MCU. It only has 2048 Bytes of memory. Considering a double takes 8 bytes (64bits) on its own. 640 * 14 * 8 = 71680 bytes.

Does the data you are storing need to be doubles? If you are working with doubles, Arduino is probably very underpowered for what you are trying to do. What is the use case of this array? Even as the smallest data type, it would still be 8960 bytes. If you are storing all Boolean values (1 or 0), then you could store them as individual bits and only take up 1120 bytes.

A little data on what you are trying to do can get you a better answer.

Comment: I am trying to receive an array from Matlab via serial communication that has values upto 4 decimal places.

Comment: Can you break the array into chunks? Might be best to handle only what you can at a time. Or handle each piece of the array as you get it. Are you trying to display data? What is the end state of the array from Matlab? Smart coding could make the array unnecessary.

Comment: Will it help if I interface an SD card with the Arduino and store data on it instead?

Comment: That would help immensely for a storage situation. If you need to actually process the data, understand the implications of arduino floating point math. See the chart below for a small idea of how long it could take to process the data:

http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php/topic,40901.0.html